# ¿Cómo enviar datos de una pagina JSP a un Servlet sin un form?

Tags: java, jsp, java-ee, servlets

Tengo un problema. No logro recibir un valor por `GET` en el `Servlet`, no se por qué.
Aquí el código JSP:

```
<html>
```

```
        <%
            List<String> listaDeCategorias = (List<String>) request.getAttribute("listaDeCategorias");
            String busquedaCategoria = (String)request.getAttribute("busquedaCategoria");

            for(String categoria : listaDeCategorias){
                if(categoria.equals( busquedaCategoria )){

        %>

        <option value="<%=categoria%>" selected><%=categoria%></option>
        <%} else {%>

        <option value="<%=categoria%>"><%=categoria%></option>
        <%}}%>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Filtrar">

</form>

<br>

<%
    List<Libro> listaDeLibros = (List<Libro>) request.getAttribute("listaDeLibros");

    for(Libro libro : listaDeLibros){
%>
    <%=libro.getIsbn()%>
    <%=libro.getTitulo()%>
    <%=libro.getCategoria()%>


    <a href="BorrarController?isbn = <%=libro.getIsbn()%>" >Borrar</a>
    <a href="EditarLibroController?isbn = <%=libro.getIsbn()%>">Editar</a>
    <br>
<%}%>

<a href="index.jsp">Registrar otro libro</a>
```

En la parte de la etiqueta

```
<a href="BorrarController?isbn = <%=libro.getIsbn()%>" >Borrar</a>
```

Quiero mandar el código isbn del libro por la `url` al `Servlet`. El enlace me lleva al `Servlet`, pero el `Servlet` no lee el dato mandado por la `url`.
Código del `Servlet`:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String isbn = request.getParameter("isbn");

    Libro libro = new Libro();
    libro.borrar(isbn);

    response.sendRedirect("MostrarLibrosController");

}
```

}

Agradezco sus aportes.

Comment: en la url que se forma en el navegador cual es? Si lleva algun espacio se va a formar otra url y por lo tanto no va a tomar los datos de manera correcta

Comment: es la url del servlet :<url-pattern>/BorrarController</url-pattern>

Comment: tambien se debe a eso si no añadiste tu mapeo de servlet a tu web.xml y recuerda que en el <url-pattern>/BorrarController</url-pattern> debe de ir el mismo nombre en el WebServlet @WebServlet("/BorrarController")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema que estan formando URL con espacios y eso por defecto te agrega un %20% en la url y nunca va a llegar el parametro que deseas.

Cambia tus href por estos:

```html
<a href="BorrarController?isbn=<%=libro.getIsbn()%>" >Borrar</a>
<a href="EditarLibroController?isbn=<%=libro.getIsbn()%>">Editar</a>
```

Tambien debes de fijarte como esta configurado tu web.xml:

```
<url-pattern>/BorrarController</url-pattern>
```

Y que el nombre del serlvlet sea el mismo que previamente configuraste en el xml:

```
@WebServlet("/BorrarController")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, el problema eran las URL con espacios, vaya tonteria la mia, no sabia lo de %20% en los espacion de la URL

Comment: si es un error que a veces se llega a cometer y como no sale error de nada uno cree que el código esta mal.. Saludos